# longtable caption --- color or redefinition

Tags: captions, longtable

Dear latexperts:  I am experimenting with pandoc as a text processor that translates into LaTeX.  This means that the LaTeX coding is mostly out of my control.

pandoc uses `longtable` for its table environment, which in turn redefines the caption macro everytime `longtable` is invoked. Styling control of the caption is accomplished through `caption.sty`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,color,caption}

\begin{document}
{
 \color{blue}
 \begin{longtable}[c]{lrr}
    left & mid & right \\
    \hline
    \caption{Why is this caption not blue??}
  \end{longtable}
  blue after text
}
\end{document}
```

I wish I could just redefine the caption in the preamble altogether, but the `\longtable` macro at the start of `\begin{longtable}` wipes it.  I cannot omit `caption.sty` altogether (it is emitted by pandoc, with a couple of options).  As said, I am pretty much stuck with the pandoc LaTeX code.  I can only define further TeX macros in a style file to get my desired looks, which is enclosed after `caption.sty` is included.

I searched the doc for `caption.sty` for color, but color is not mentioned.

So, how do I convince caption not to switch color back to black, but to leave it as is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with the `caption` package by placing:

```
\captionsetup[table]{font={color=blue}}
```

in the preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,color,caption}
\captionsetup[table]{font={color=blue}}

\begin{document}
{
 \color{blue}
 \begin{longtable}[c]{lrr}
    left & mid & right \\
    \hline
    \caption{Why is this caption not blue??}
  \end{longtable}
  blue after text
}

\end{document}
```

Generally placing caption above the table is somewhat good for readability. For figures it comes below.